# pullToRefresh crashes when changing views

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I change between two views, on the 4-5 change my app crashes
I used zombie to find out with object was called and it's

```
[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
```

I'm using SVPullToRefresh library 
in the first view I have a carousel and the second a SVPullToRefreshView

UIViewController being as generic as it comes I'm having trouble pinpointing the reason for the crash

here's the method which is shown at crash time by xcode

```
- (void)addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:(void (^)(void))actionHandler {
LogDebug(@"START - init pull to refresh");

if(!self.pullToRefreshView) {
    LogDebug(@"Pull to refresh view is nil, we create it");
    SVPullToRefreshView *view = [[SVPullToRefreshView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -SVPullToRefreshViewHeight, self.bounds.size.width, SVPullToRefreshViewHeight)];
    view.pullToRefreshActionHandler = actionHandler;
    view.scrollView = self;
    [self addSubview:view];

    view.originalTopInset = self.contentInset.top;

    self.pullToRefreshView = view;
    self.showsPullToRefresh = YES;
}
```

}

here's the parent caller

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

__block BlogViewController *blockSelf = self;
[self.articleScrollView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    LogDebug(@"start refresh");
    [blockSelf refresh];
    [blockSelf.articleScrollView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
}];
```

}

EDIT :
If I remove the test `(!self.pullToRefreshView)` it works however the allocations pile up

Comment: What did you learn from running with breakpoints? (Assuming you tried breakpoints before Zombies)

Comment: I learnt that it's my pullToRefreshView that is nil in the triggerPullToRefresh Method